# Can not configure 5GHz WiFi band for Beaglebone AI

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, beagleboard, wifi, hostapd

I am trying to configure 5GHz WiFi band for my new Beaglebone AI.

What I am doing is

```
cp /tmp/hostapd-bbai.conf to /etc/hostapd.conf
```

opening /etc/default/bb-wl18xx and changing USE_GENERATED_HOSTAPD to 'no'

```
USE_GENERATED_HOSTAPD=no
```

in order to use `/etc/hostapd.conf` file instead of generated conf file from `/tmp`

this method works perfect for `'b'` and `'g'` but I can not configure to `'a'` in order to use 5GHz band

Can anyone help me regarding this?

this is my hostapd.conf

```
interface=SoftAp0
ssid=BeagleBone-59A4
hw_mode=a
channel=1
wmm_enabled=1
country_code=IN
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1
wmm_enabled=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=BeagleBone
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Beagle Bone AI WIFI stack is more powerful and its auto handle.
if still you facing issue regarding any other interfaces then please follow below link :

https://github.com/MalavPatel3501/BeagleBone-AI--mpBBAI-IO-Python-Library

In this project you got .dts file and all pin muxing steps. Moreover i puts some example code in this project.

Comment: Hello @Malav I tested the same thing for 5GHz. I Observed the same behaviour. Thanks for sharing this link. It's quite useful.